# Using Selenium IDE with Firefox 10?

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

Last time I used Selenium IDE, I had a previous version of Firefox. Now, after many upgrades (would't be able to say exactly how many), record and playback tests aren't working.

My actual version of Firefox is 10.0.2. Is this the problem? [Here](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#browsers) it says that Firefox 3, 4 and 5 recorded tests, but Firefox 6 doesn't. But I find it strange that the site doesn't mention anything about versions 7, 8, 9 and the latest one, 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla's decision to release a new Firefox major version every day or two (OK, it isn't *quite* that bad, but still ...) has outstripped the Selenium Project's ability to keep its documentation up to date.  Selenium IDE 1.6.0 (released January 26, 2012) fully supports Firefox 10 (see the [IDE release notes](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes) for history).

Comment: Thanks!! I was being misguided by the documentation!